# Moving from one hard drive to another

Tags: configuration, backup, hard-disk, migration

I'm running Arch on a laptop and I fell into a really nice newer hard drive. I'd like to move over to the new drive, but I'm not sure what the safest/smartest way to move from one hard drive to another is.

How should I migrate from one drive to a newer one?

Comment: With all partitions that matter, as-is?

Comment: I hope to increase the partition sizes...the truth is, this is a one part SSD (for operating system stuff, I presume) and the rest is the more traditional mechanical head style (for data storage, primarily, I presume)...so, I will have to do some rework on the partition sizes... furthermore,its a larger capacity drive as well.

Comment: What partitions do you currently have and which ones do you want to enlarge? And please search this site, we've had many questions on this topic and one of them probably covers your case; which one depends on whether you're using LVM/dmcrypt/… and what kind of resizing you want.